# Load frozen graph in OpenCV DNN C++

Tags: opencv, c++11, tensorflow2.0

I get the following error while loading a frozen graph in C++ using the given code. What am I doing wrong? Please help me to solve this problem.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():  OpenCV(4.1.0)
> /home/Downloads/opencv-4.1.0/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_graph_simplifier.cpp:860:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) nodesMapIt != nodesMap.end() in
> function 'sortByExecutionOrder'
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;

int main()
{
    // load the neural network model
    cv::dnn::Net inputNet;
    inputNet = cv::dnn::readNet("frozen_graph.pb");
    //inputNet = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("frozen_graph.pb");
}
```

I got the frozen_graph.pb using the following conversion in python and tensorflow 2.4

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

loaded = tf.saved_model.load('savedmodel')
infer = loaded.signatures['serving_default']

f = tf.function(infer).get_concrete_function(input_1=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 160, 160, 3], dtype=tf.float32))
f2 = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(f)
graph_def = f2.graph.as_graph_def()

# write frozen graph (single file) to disk
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('frozen_graph.pb', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

and I can successfully use it with the following code in python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"1.jpg")
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('frozen_graph.pb')
imgn = imgn.astype(np.float32)
# create blob from image (opencv dnn way of pre-processing)
input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(imgn, 1, (160,160), 0, swapRB=False, crop=False)
net.setInput(input_blob)
feature_vector_dnn = net.forward()
```

These [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sortByExecutionOrder) are related but can't help.
opencv version: 4.1.0 both in C++ and Python

Comment: please check opencv versions for c++ & python

Comment: save version 4.1.0 of opencv in python in C++

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade the version of OpenCV to 4.5.3 in C++ and it will solve the problem.

OpenCV 4.1.x and 4.2.x cannot handle frozen_graph created/converted in TensorFlow 2.x. I'm not sure about OpenCV 4.3.x and 4.4.x.